# cannot style file button in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, file-upload

I have a file button for uploading files like:

```
<input type="file" name="tx_searchdp_searchdp[data][file]" id="uploadBtn" class="upload">
```

However, the styling for it does not get applied in IE (any version, including the latest). In all other browsers the styling is good.

Any way to style this button in IE?

my css:

```
input#uploadBtn {
  background: url("img/uploadbtn.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0 none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  height: 38px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 38px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
background-image: url('img/uploadbtn.png');
   background-size: 100% 100%;
```

etc...

instead of:

```
background: url("img/uploadbtn.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```